# How to make more advanced SPF controls with cb policy in Zimbra?

Tags: spf, zimbra

I have a mail server with Zimbra community and a few domains. I use cbpolicy for SPF control, quota and stuff. SPF controls are working successfully. However, when I disabled the SPF check for one of my domains, it worked correctly for emails from external domains, but failed to work correctly for internal email addresses. For example, when [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) with SPF check turned off tries to send mail to [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) with spf check on, '554 5.7.1 test@example: Sender address rejected: Failed SPF check; it returns error.

Can someone help me with getting this done correctly?

The webmail interface works as expected for both open and closed domains with SPF control. For e-mails coming from internal e-mail addresses and external e-mail addresses, SPF control works correctly as programmed, on or off. The above behavior only occurs when using POP or IMAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it this way:

First, I created the uncheck-spf rule and set the priority to 1000. Then I wrote source as members and %internal_domain as destination. I created a group called internal_domain from the groups. I've added all my internal domains to this list. Then I added a new rule (uncheck-spf ) for spf checks. I connected this to the uncheck-spf rule I created before, usespf = yes and registered it as reject failed spf = no. When I tried it later, the rule worked as it should within a few minutes. The policyd-web-ui was very helpful while doing all this.

Maybe it will save other people's time.